# How to read from a file and direct output to a file if a file name is given in the command line, and printing to console if no argument given

Tags: perl, redirect, md5, output

I made a file, "rootfile", that contains paths to certain files and the perl program mymd5.perl gets the md5sum for each file and prints it in a certain order. How do I redirect the output to a file if a name is given in the command line? For instance if I do

```
perl mymd5.perl md5file
```

then it will feed output to md5file. And if I just do

```
perl mydm5.perl
```

it will just print to the console.

This is my rootfile:

```
/usr/local/courses/cs3423/assign8/cmdscan.c
/usr/local/courses/cs3423/assign8/driver.c
/usr/local/courses/cs3423/assign1/xpostitplus-2.3-3.diff.gz
```

This is my program right now:

```
open($in, "rootfile") or die "Can't open rootfile: $!";
$flag = 0;

if ($ARGV[0]){
        open($out,$ARGV[0]) or die "Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!";
        $flag = 1;
}

if ($flag == 1) {
        select $out;
}

while ($line = <$in>) {
        $md5line = `md5sum $line`;
        @md5arr = split(" ",$md5line);
        if ($flag == 0) {
                printf("%s\t%s\n",$md5arr[1],$md5arr[0]);
        }
}
close($out);
```

Comment: Actually not clear on what it is you're after. Can you be more precise?

Comment: when your `flag = 1` you will print nothing because you have wrapped your printf statement under the condition that flag must be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't give a **FILEHANDLE** to **print** or **printf**, the output will go to **STDOUT** (the console).

There are several way you can redirect the output of your **print** statements.

```
select $out; #everything you print after this line will go the file specified by the filehandle $out.

... #your print statements come here.

close $out; #close connection when done to avoid counfusing the rest of the program.

#or you can use the filehandle right after the print statement as in:

print $out "Hello World!\n";
```

Comment: Okay I have tried this method but my output file is blank. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a filename influenced by the value in @ARGV as follows:

This will take the name of the file in `$ARGV[0]` and use it to name a new file, `edit.$ARGV[0]`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open my $input, '<', $file or die $!;

my $editedfile = "edit.$file";
open my $name_change, '>', $editedfile or die $!;

if ($input eq "md5file"){    

while ($in){
    # Do something...
    print $name_change "$_\n";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my $md5line = `md5sum $_`;
    my @md5arr = split( " ", $md5line );
    printf( "%s\t%s\n", $md5arr[1], $md5arr[0] );
}
```

Usage: `perl mydm5.pl rootfile [>md5file]`

The last, optional parameter will direct output to the file md5file; if absent, the results are printed to the console.